# Why do I have some content in my resolv.conf file on GCE?

Tags: linux, dns, google-compute-engine, resolve

I have this content in my Google Compute Engine vm in the /etc/resolv.conf file:

```
domain c.company.internal.
search c.company.internal. 160467777293.google.internal. google.internal.
nameserver 169.254.169.254
nameserver 10.240.0.1
```

Why do I have that and what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This allows resolution of DNS names within your project. For example, for one GCE VM to talk to another GCE VM, you can just use its hostname to connect to it (which you have chosen), rather than its internal IP (which is auto-assigned).

Also, the [fully-qualified domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) of a GCE VM is of the format:

> [vm-name].c.[project-name].internal

You can see what it is on any given VM by running `hostname -f`.

This also allows you to resolve special hostnames such as [`metadata`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata) (the GCE metadata server, [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name): `metadata.google.internal`), which is actually located at `169.254.169.254`.

Answer (score 1):

One additional note; the last two lines are the DNS nameservers that you use -- they are both pointed to the Google-internal resolver with the behavior that Misha pointed out.

If you switch these to e.g. `8.8.8.8`, you'll use Google's public DNS resolvers. You'll lose access to the internal names if you do this, but you could potentially point at your company's internal DNS servers to access those names if you wanted to.